# tel: url scheme showing as action sheet in ios 13?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tel

How to show tel url scheme as alert in ios 13

I want make a call from app so i am using te url scheme it is presenting as alert below ios 13 but from ios 13 it is displaying as action sheet

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:%@",number]];
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Apple have changed the presentation to an action sheet. There's nothing you can do.

Comment: I haven't tested because I don't have iOS13 but I found online that there is another [undocumented] URL scheme for this purpose, `telprompt:`, perhaps it would use the old behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes from iOS13 its showing as action sheet .
you observe in other applications which are making call are showing as action sheet only .